# "Select all" contacts for e-mail in Outlook?

Tags: outlook.com

I was just involuntarily switched over to Outlook.com from Hotmail. I need to regularly "select all" contacts for bulk e-mails. I have not been able to figure out how to do that now that it's changed. Please tell me there is a way!

Answer (score 2):

When creating a new email, click "To" on the left-hand side and select the name of a group you want to send to.

[image]

If you don't have a group already set up, you can go into People (using the little down arrow in the top left) and select all the people you want to from your list and add to a new group.

[image]

Comment: Not very helpful since the OP wants to be able to "select all" rather than select people one at a time.

Comment: You can select everyone in your contact list at once and add them to the same group. Then you can send to that group whenever you want. It's about as close as you can get with the current functionality.

Comment: There are Bookmarklets out there that make it easy to check **all** checkboxes on a page, so this isn't as untenable as it could be. (I'd post one here, but it's too long for the comment box.)

Answer (score 2):

Check the box for the first contact then hold <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>arrow down</kbd> to select all.

Comment: does not work for me